# At what point is the input on the command line parsed into process.argv in node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, node.js, shell

I wrote an application that takes command line input, except the input doesn't come from bash or any other shell. What I mean is that I get user input through another means and I end up with a string. If this input had come through the command line like normal then node would have magically already parsed the command line arguments into a proper array at `process.argv`.

It seems pretty simple to duplicate this behavior at first glance because it's just a matter of `str.split(' ')` right? Well not quite. The `argv` magic does a little pre-processing on the input, ensuring that things like `"hello there"` ends up as one array item rather than two because of the quotation marks. There may be other things it does to build this array that I'm not aware of as well.

Rather than try to duplicate this logic through trial and error I was wondering if any of you could point me to the place where this logic happens. I have no idea where inside the node project this `process.argv` array is defined. I tried searching through the source but I have no idea what I'm really looking for. Can anyone point me to where this logic lives? I would like to duplicate it so that I can be confident the input is being parsed the exact same way the shell/node would.

#### Update:

All I want here is the array parsing. I don't need any text in the string to be interpreted in any other way. I just want to take a string and break it apart into the exact same array that node would have exposed to me as `process.argv`. I was just hoping to find this parsing logic and either copy it or port it into JavaScript.

Once I have the array I run it through an options parser library ([yargs](https://github.com/chevex/yargs), a fork of [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist)). The option parser does not understand string input, only an array. This is convenient if I am trying to pass in `process.argv`, but not so convenient if I need to turn the string into the array myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing you're referring to typically comes from a shell, e.g. `bash`, and is far from trivial. This happens *before* NodeJS is even invoked; that is, it happens by the shell which is *about* to execute NodeJS.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but if the input you take is meant to be from a trusted user, then you could just run the command using `child_process.exec`, which passes the command to a shell for interpretation. See http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback for details, including an example that uses glob expansion and a pipeline.

If, however, there is any chance that the command is not to be trusted (e.g. maybe you don't want to allow pipelines?), then you are better off defining a restricted acceptable syntax and just parsing that.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is turn a simple string into the same parsed array located at `process.argv`. Unfortunately this input is not coming from a trusted source and I cannot pass it directly to a shell. Do you know where I might find the logic the shell uses to create this array? I don't need the commands/arguments to be interpreted; I only need to parse a string the same way the shell would parse it and end up with the same array that would show up in `process.argv`. The actual text in the string need not correspond with real commands in a shell.

Comment: More detail: Once I have the array I run it through an options parser library ([yargs](https://github.com/chevex/yargs), a fork of [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist)). The option parser does not understand string input, only an array. This is convenient if I am trying to pass in `process.argv`, but not so convenient if I need to turn the string into the array myself.

Comment: You'll find the "logic" for how the shell does this in the source code for the shell. E.g., here's where you can find the source for `bash`: <http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/>

Comment: I appreciate it but I was hoping to get pointed to the place in the source where this happens. I've already been pouring over lots of source code to no avail.

Comment: IIRC  you won't find something that localized - I believe it's all wrapped up in the overall lexer/parser that BASH uses for everything.  You might want to consider the alternate route, of formatting your node.js argv input in such a way that you can write to THAT spec for  your other way.

Comment: lol that's actually what I am trying to do. I'm the maintainer for the [yargs](https://github.com/chevex/yargs) fork and I'm trying to add this functionality into the library so it can take a string or an array.

Comment: Alex, I hesitate to say this because I don't know your full context, but this really strikes me as a bit of a misguided effort. Shell parsing syntax is super-arcane, and I think if anything you'd be much better off defining (and documenting) a syntax that makes sense in your specific context — e.g. just handle quoted arguments but no filename globbing, variable substitution, brace expansion, process pipelining, command substitution, etc. — and implementing that.

Comment: @danfuzz I'm beginning to agree. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @AlexFord - did you end up solving this problem? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do something similar and I'm considering just executing another script in a child process that outputs the args, and capturing that.

The args bash script is named 'args' and is simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(JSON.stringify(process.argv));
```

The main bash script (in the same directory) then looks like this:

```
var exampleString = "foo bar 'blah blah'";
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(__dirname+'/args '+exampleString, function(error, stdout, stderr){
  var args = JSON.parse(stdout);
  // args now split
  console.log(args);
});
```

Which gives you:

```
[ 'node',
'/Users/.../args',
'foo',
'bar',
'blah blah' ]
```

That works for me but I haven't tried it very seriously yet.